# How could it be that static field is not initialized before it is accessed?

Tags: c#, .net, static, initialization

I have following code:

```
public class BufferedChart
{
  ...
  private static LineClass m_lineDrawingAlgorithm = new LineClass();
  ...

  public BitmapData LockBitmap()
  {
    ...
    unsafe
    {
      // Clear bitmap data (clear bitmap)
      m_lineDrawingAlgorithm.ClearBitmapData(ref (*((int*)bmData.Scan0.ToPointer())), m_bufferBitmap.Width * m_bufferBitmap.Height);
      m_cleared = true;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

And it fails with NullReferenceException at the access to the lineDrawingAlgorithm. It is not 100% reproducible but still how can it be possible that this reference is null? Is it related to `unsafe` block or somehow related to the fact that LineClass is COM object?

Comment: There are lots of property accesses in there. Are you sure that it is `m_lineDrawingAlgorithm` that's null?

Comment: Debug it and find which accessor is null.

Comment: At the moment I'm pretty sure it concerns m_lineDrawingAlgorithm. And it have never reproduced under debugger.